# In Perl, how can I obtain the full path of a file on the visitor's computer from an HTML file upload field?

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I am try to print the filename with path from input tag. But it prints only file name not print with path.

My html script

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="file.pl" method="post">
<input type = "file" name = "name">
<input type = submit>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My perl script

```
use CGI;
$cgi = CGI->new();
$filename = $cgi-> param('name');
print "$filename";
```

In above script i select the file from **D:\new_folder\file.txt** it prints only the **file.txt** how can i change it.

Comment: I imagine it would be a browser setting whether or not to even *send* that information to the server.  Generally the server doesn't need that information.  And basic information security demands that any information a party doesn't need shouldn't be provided to that party.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with Perl. You could program a web browser that would do this, but real browsers have stopped passing the full path name for good reason. For example, see [Firefox bug report #143220](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=143220):

> John Keiser (jkeiser) 2002-08-31 13:57:11 PDT
>
> There is no spec that says that, but we explicitly try not to send it to avoid
> sending information about the user's local filesystem.

See also the [release notes for Firefox 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/3/Updating_web_applications#File_upload_fields):

> #### File upload fields
>
> In prior versions of Firefox, there were cases in which when the user submitted a file for uploading, the entire path of the file was available to the web application. This privacy concern has been resolved in Firefox 3; now only the filename itself is available to the web application.